# Zip file is getting corrupted after uploaded to server using C#

Tags: c#, ftp, dotnetzip

I am trying to **upload a zip** file to server using `C# (Framework 4)`and following is my code.

```
string ftpUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ftpAddress"];
string ftpUsername = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ftpUsername"];
string ftpPassword = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ftpPassword"];  
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ftpUrl + "Transactions.zip");  
request.Proxy = new WebProxy(); //-----The requested FTP command is not supported when using HTTP proxy.
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUsername, ftpPassword);
StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader(fileToBeUploaded);
byte[] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
sourceStream.Close();
request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;
Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
requestStream.Close();
FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
Console.WriteLine("Upload File Complete, status {0}", response.StatusDescription);
            response.Close();
```

The zip file is uploaded successfully, but when I tried to open the zip file from server(manually), it showed me `Unexpected end of archive` error.
For file compression I am using `Ionic.zip dll`. Before transferring the zip file, I was able to extract successfully.

Any help appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Try to avoid sourceStream.ReadToEnd() and copy bytes directly from sourceStream to requestStream

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader(fileToBeUploaded);
byte[] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
```

`StreamReader` (and any `TextReader`) is for *text* data. A zip file isn't text data.

Just use:

```
byte[] fileContents = File.ReadAllBytes(fileToBeUploaded);
```

That way you're not treating binary data as text, so it shouldn't get corrupted.

Or alternatively, don't load it all into memory separately - just stream the data:

```
using (var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    using (var input = File.OpenRead(fileToBeUploaded))
    {
        input.CopyTo(requestStream);
    }
}
```

Also note that you should be using `using` statements for all of these streams, rather than just calling `Close` - that way the resources will be disposed even if an exception is thrown.

Comment: Is there any way to know whether our file is uploaded successfully or not, like `status.code =OK`?

Comment: @user1671639: Yes - get the status code from the `FtpWebResponse` and see whether it's `CommandOK` or `FileActionOK`. (There may be some others to look for - experiment with it.) I'd expect it to throw an exception when you get the response if it's failed, to be honest.

Comment: I tried specifying `FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();` and I got it from `response.StatusDescription = "226 File receive OK."`.  But I am already using `using` statement as you advised.  Does this affect my program?

Comment: @user1671639: I don't know what you mean. Yes, you should use a `using` statement for the response... but I'd advise using the status *code* rather than the description.

Comment: I have "*.bin" which is getting corrupt. I tried your way ,but its not helping.Any help or guess.Thanks

Comment: @KumarHarsh: No, there isn't nearly enough information for me to help you based on that.

Comment: @JonSkeet ,my answer is below .Can I by any chance recover those corrupted files ?I HTTP PUT those file in IIS WEDAV  folder using below code