# File.ReadAllBytes(file) supports only 2GB - alternative?

Tags: c#, file-upload, ftp

I want to upload a file to a server via ftp, but I can't get the file-bytes, because `byte[] fileContents = File.ReadAllBytes(file);` only supports files with an amount of **2GB**.

How can I solve the problem?

Is there any alternative to `File.ReadAllBytes(file)` ?

I don't want to use a `StreamReader`, because of [Zip file is getting corrupted after uploaded to server using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16495735/zip-file-is-getting-corrupted-after-uploaded-to-server-using-c-sharp)

Comment: If you're just uploading a file, why are you reading its contents? Maybe you can get away with just File.Move.

Comment: Read and post the file block by block (for ex using 64K blocks). Do you think loading a huge file to memory is a good thing?

Comment: It's the first time I work with ftp coding, and I found some examples, which first load the file. How can I post the file block by block ?

Comment: @Ismoh It is not related with *ftp-coding*. Suppose you want to copy a file. Would you read all file at once and write it to another location? What if the file is much much bigger than your memory?

Comment: Oh yes. You'r right, but I don't know how to read a file in blocks. Let me look up this at google.

Comment: See the methods `stream.Read` `stream.Write` and for your special case `stream.CopyTo`

Comment: Thanks. Maybe you can put the comment in an answer, so that I can accept it as 'problem solved', because I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/230128/how-do-i-copy-the-contents-of-one-stream-to-another